# При подключении к удаленному серверу с БД на MSSQL2005, возникает ошибка undefine mssql_connect.

Tags: php, sql-server, freebsd

Здравствуйте!

Ситуация следующая:

1. **Использую: FreeBSD, PHP5.3.8.**
2. PHP не понимает функцию mssql_connect.

Сделал проверку:

> <?php
>
> ```
> if (function_exists('mssql_connect'))
> {
>     echo 'Библиотека php_dblib.dll установлена правильно!';
> } ?>
> ```

На что я получил: undefine mssql_connect
Посмотрел что установлено в php, выполнил следующую функцию:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Где не увидел ни в одном месте про mssql.
Раскомментировал в php.ini строку mssql. Результата никакого.
Установил:

```
- Freetds 7.0
- DBO_BDLIB
```

То же не помогло.
Подскажите что нужно еще установить и где взять. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: А вот здесь не про это? http://www.lissyara.su/articles/freebsd/www/php+mssql/

Comment: спасибо за информацию. попробую и отпишусь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через port подтянул недостающие библиотеки. MSSQL заработала!)